# styling issues and accessing child

Tags: javascript, css

```
<div className={classes.scoreContainer}>
    <span className="label">
      {`${scorecard.score.totalRuns||0}/${scorecard.score
      .totalWickets||0}${isCurrentInning?"*":""}`}
    <span className="overclass">
        ({`${scorecard.score.overs}.${
        scorecard.score.overBalls
        }ov`}) // want to change font of this
    </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I want the bot the data to be displayed on same line but the  data inside second span with different font size .

Here is the css for this .

```
    scoreContainer {
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "flex-end",
      "&>span:first-child": {
      fontWeight: 520,
      },
      "&>span:second-child":{
      fontWeight:10,
      },
      "&>span:nth-child(2)": {
      fontWeight: 300,
      fontSize: "2vh",
      }
    }
```

However I am not able to acess that span properly .We can't create two spans and put them inside div as this will shit them on two different lines .
This is not what we can do

```
    <div>
      <span>data1</span>
       <span>data2</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: I notice that it was there is another `span` inside of `span`. Won't you be able to access the second `span` with `>span>span`?

Answer (score 0):

```
"&>span>span":{
    fontWeight:10,
    /* fontWeight: 300, don't know if you need 10 or 300 */
    fontSize: "2vh",
}
```

As @Mukyuu suggested, the above would be the selector for the `span` inside the first (and only) child `span` in the `div`